# How can i store each line from Edit Box GUI into an array? [Autohotkey GUI]

Tags: autohotkey

I need to store each line from the text (EditBox GUI element) into an array. The user will type sentences in each line, and each line needs to be stored in the array. Here's an example of what I mean:

[image: Example Picture]

```
Gui Add, Edit, xs R20 w550 vArrayTextArea, This needs to be the first item in array`n This needs to 
be the second item in array `nThis needs to be the thrid item in array..

; Button
Gui Add, Button, w350 gCreateScript xs, BUTTON

Gui Show
Return

CreateScript:
Gui Submit, NoHide
global ArrayEdit:=ArrayTextArea

Return
```

Answer (score 2):

For example `StrSplit()`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StrSplit.htm)</sup> would do this very easily.
Example script:

```
Gui, Add, Edit, R20 w550 vArrayTextArea, % "Line1`nLine2`nLine3"
Gui, Add, Button, w350 gCreateScript, BUTTON
Gui, Show
Return

CreateScript:
    Gui, Submit, NoHide
    LineArray := StrSplit(ArrayTextArea, "`n", "`r")
    for each, line in LineArray
        MsgBox, % line
Return
```